# Getting "flogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached" when adding Brocade switches to Rancid

Tags: rancid

I've set up Rancid on my Ubuntu 14.04 system for a couple of devices which all work fine except for all devices of type 'foundry' (Brocade). Every hour a cron job executes rancid-run as the rancid user. I tested both the **flogin** as the **clogin** binary login scripts.

**flogin**

This is what I see in every log:

```
<switch>: End of run not found 0 || 0
<switch> flogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
<switch>: missed cmd(s): show version,show flash,show module,write term,show running-config,show chassis
<switch>: End of run not found
```

My .clogin file seems to be fine:

```
rancid@ubuntu14.04:~$ cat /home/rancid/.cloginrc 
add autoenable * 1
add method * ssh
add user * rancid
add password * Jg278edd.fisd%1y
```

SSH'ing to the switches the regular way works fine. But running the flogin script manually gives me this:

```
rancid@ubuntu14.04:/var/lib/rancid/bin$ ./flogin -c 'show version' <switch>
s0.nikhef.nl
spawn ssh -c 3des -x -l rancid s0.nikhef.nl
rancid@s0.nikhef.nl's password: 
SSH@s0.nikhef.nl>
Error: TIMEOUT reached
```

It takes about 10 seconds to login and after that it seems that it doesn't execute the command I specify after the -c flag. And after another 10-20 seconds it exits after it reached Rancid's TIMEOUT value.

**clogin**

This script works just fine... (but it doesn't go to exec mode, it ignores autoenable 1)..

```
rancid@ubuntu14.04:/var/lib/rancid/bin$ ./clogin -c 'show version' <switch>
<switch>
spawn ssh -c 3des -x -l rancid <switch>
rancid@<switch>'s password: 
SSH@<switch>>
SSH@<switch>>terminal length 0
Invalid input -> terminal length 0
Type ? for a list
SSH@<switch>>terminal width 132
Invalid input -> terminal width 132
Type ? for a list
SSH@<switch>>show version
 SW: Version 04.2.00b Copyright (c) 1996-2010 Brocade Communications Systems, 
...

SSH@<switch>>exitConnection to <switch> closed by remote host.
Connection to <switch> closed.
```

So I figured, why not replace flogin's code with clogin's code and all be fine, right? Manual test confirmed that, but doing a rancid-run did not get the configs, but just shows this in the logs:

```
<switch>: End of run not found 0 || 0
<switch>: missed cmd(s): show chassis,show running-config,write term,show flash,show version,show module
<switch>: End of run not found
```

What is left to debug?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with foundry devices the autoenable / no enable part of the .cloginrc file gets ignored. I fixed my problem by having users automatically go to privileged exec mode:

```
SSH@<switch>(config)#aaa authentication login privilege-mode
```

After executing rancid-run again I was able to get all my switches' config successfully.